# How to set the Windows default keyboard shortcuts in Ubuntu?

Tags: matlab

I am working on MATLAB, and it is kind of annoying not being able to use typical shortcuts as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. I wonder if it is possible to have the default Windows keyboard shortcuts in Ubuntu.

Comment: Open  `System settings`, go to `keyboard` and select `Shortcuts` tab. Check if you see any interesting things there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to `Preferences-->Keyboard-->Shortcuts`

In the Active settings dropdown choose `Windows Default Set`.

Comment: Your answer needs to get updated: Looks like on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS it says "Windows," but not "windows, default setting". So is there a difference? Plz, thanks!

Comment: @Stackcraft_noob it's the same (obviously).